# Set margins to FrameLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, viewgroup

I create and add fragments to a view programmatically.
Here is my code:

```
CollectionsSlideShowFragment fragment = new CollectionsSlideShowFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("collections", gson.toJson(collectionsSlideShow));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(this);
        addFragment(R.id.collectionsSlideshow, fragment);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setMargins(0, (int) UiUtils.dp2px(15), 0, 0);
        view.setId(R.id.collectionsSlideshow);
        contentContainer.addView(view, params);

protected Fragment addFragment(int container, Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    return fragment;
}
```

but adding margins to the framelayout has no effect, I have reviews other answers on SO recommending setting gravity, but that doesn't have any effect too.
How do I set margins to fragment?

Comment: Set the margins in fragment `onViewCreated()` method instead. Your code where you initialize your fragment should only create the fragment and set arguments. Nothing else.

Comment: Hey, this code is in activity not in fragment.

Comment: Doesn't matter. When the fragment is created using fragment transaction the lifecycle methods of the fragment will be called, including `oncreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`.